# How to add tabs to panels setting page?

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I want to add additional vertical tabs (marked with red) in screenshot, but have had no luck with google or documentation.
[image]

How does one add tabs here?

Comment: Wow, interesting question, I have absolutely no idea! :) I'll see if I can find out. Out of curiosity, what are you gonna do with the extra tabs?

Comment: Letharion, thank you for correcting my mistakes. I want to add extra asset settings per each aspect (block, node, node-type, url and certainly panel) for my asset module. In our company, we have already tried to use "code per node" module, inline css and js code (in the node, views, block), drupal_add_* in template.php or own "theme" module. "code per node" is not designed for version controlling, all other ways just inconvenient. Developed by me module allows you to connect asset path to any aspect(node, url, panel..) and configure it.

Comment: Really interesting question...can you override the default panels module...just a shot..will look more into it and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those vertical items are internally called "operations" and are implemented by task_handlers plugins although some of them are *hardcoded* in page_manager. You can see some examples in:

```
ctools/page_manager/plugins/task_handlers/http_response.inc 
panels/plugins/task_handlers/panel_context.inc
```

You may also find more info in [page_manager_render_operations()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!page_manager!page_manager.admin.inc/function/page_manager_render_operations/7)  docstrings.